# Errors attempting to publish a project from Visual Studio Express 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to publish an application to a local intranet site, and am getting the following errors:-

```
Unable to add 'ControlPanel.aspx' to the Web site.  550 ControlPanel.aspx: Access is denied. 
Unable to add 'Default.aspx' to the Web site.  550 Default.aspx: Access is denied. 
.
.
.
Unable to add folder 'bin' to the Web site.  Cannot create folder "bin".
```

but I can connect to the location using ftp and do anything I like, using the same username and password. Does anyone know why this might be?

(Although I have copied the files and the new application runs I suspect doing this has wrecked the licensing of one of the components, so I'd like to be able to try the 'official' way.)

Comment: My guess would be you dont have write permissions ( IIS_IUSRS )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it might be a good idea to ensure your visual studio configuration publishing settings have the correct user/pwd to access the directory.